# How to set up a custom server using nx and next.js combined

Tags: next.js, nxjs

I'm looking to set up a http server like the server.js described in

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server

in my nx project, however, when I add an executor to run

> node server.js

I'm getting an error

```
'../my-libs/src/lib/cursor-flash.ts`
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:1)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

How can I run this with the correct webpack config + loaders?